# Run application on IOS 5.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.2

I am using XCode 4.2 with IOS 5 to develop an application. This application doesn't include any new features provided in IOS 5.1. So, if I submit this app to App Store, can the users download it and run it on their IOS device with IOS 5.1?

Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your app will continue to be forward compatible as long as Apple doesn't depreciate anything that you're using (Mostly only happens in major releases). Overall, your app will be fine between iOS 5 and 5.1 but be sure to keep up to date on the API differences that Apple posts so that you can make changes if necessary.

As an example that isn't currently under NDA, here's a link to the iOS 4.3 - 5.0 API differences: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html